# Ubuntu 14.04 Mouse Pointer/cursor disappears when changing user

Tags: unity, mouse, multi-user

I have Ubuntu 14.04 installed (using unity) and everything seems to work fine until I try to use a second user.

Once I click to log into another user it takes me back to the login screen and once it finishes drawing the cursor vanishes.  After this point the only way to get it back is to use the arrow keys to reselect the already logged in user and log back in.  If I log out of the first user the other user account seems to gets possession of the mouse.  Is there some setting to state that the mouse cannot be claimed exclusively by one user?  This is most annoying when my Nephew comes over and I have him use the Guest Account to surf the web.  It only works if i make sure to sign out of the primary account before I leave for the day.  It has does this since I upgrade from 13.10.

Example:

1. Login screen (has pointer)
2. Login as Tom (has pointer)
3. Switch back to Login screen (NO pointer)
4. Two Possible Use Cases:

   4.1. User keyboard to login as Tom (pointer returns)

   4.2. User keyboard to login as Jerry (NO pointer)

Same thing happens if you switch users Jerry and Tom from the above example.  Whoever logs in first seems to be exclusive rights to the mouse pointer (mouse cursor) and it does not get shared to any user after that.

Comment: Welcome to askubuntu! Can you tell us what hardware you are using that displays this behaviour? Desktop or laptop, make and model? Does this sound like your issue? http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1087624

Comment: Having the same problem, I think my hardware information may be useful too: I'm using a HP Pavilion dv7 laptop, Intel Core I7 cpu, 6GB RAM, 2x500GB disk, with NVIDIA Corporation GT216M [GeForce GT 230M] (rev a2) video board. The issue you linked didn't help. Sorry. BTW, I also tried xeyes and "the eyes" don't move when I move the mouse. Seems to be stuck every time I login with a second user. Can't it be related to some permission issue?

Comment: HP Pavilion dv7-1285dx.  2.4GHz Intel Core 2 Duo P8600, 512MB Nvidia GeForce 9600M GT.

Comment: I have not tried xeyes, but yes, i believe that the mouse is not being exposed to the new user, but even the Login screen is not getting a mouse object.  I have been unable to figure out a key press combination to switch users back to the first logged in user, but I know that if I go back to the login screen (not lock screen) there is no mouse from then on, unless you relog into the primary user.

Comment: @ElderGeek This does not looks like the issue, as it only happens when changing users, and this forum talks about the cursor being invisible, my issue is that it is just not functional, as long as I use just a single login it suspends resumes locks and unlocks without the mouse going invisible, but when I try to login a second concurrent user the mouse seems to not "release" from whoever is logged in first.
Ex: Login screen has mouse, login Tom has mouse, switch to login screen, no mouse, Login as Jerry no mouse

Comment: Are Tom and Jerry members of the same groups?

Comment: I honestly don't know, I am assuming so, they were added via the "Users" dialog, but also one of them could be the "Guest" account that comes by default, same thing happens.

Comment: I just played with an external USB mouse.  If I plug in a second mouse (not have just the built-in track-pad), the pointer works.  I am guessing that it might be something with the synaptics driver?  I found another post that said to remove and install the driver, but I already did that before this post... so it did not help me at all.

Comment: This behavior seems to be similar to the bug I reported here: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/unity-settings-daemon/+bug/1362218 . You may want to mark yourself as affected there. By the way, to switch users/logout/etc using the keyboard: press **Alt** + **F10** to open the first menu in the top panel, then use the arrow keys to go to the top right system menu and select the option you want there.